# Regex to match one of any terms, some terms with spaces

Tags: regex, spam-prevention

I'm trying to write a RegEx that matches one of several terms, as part of a spam filter. The problem is, some of these terms contain spaces, and I'm having trouble writing a valid expression.

What I originally had (before multiple word temrs) was this:

```
(?i)(alzheimers|baldness|obese)
```

Now, I want to add, for example "blood pressure", but the following expression is chucking a barny:

```
(?i)(alzheimers|baldness|blood pressure|obese)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have whitespace characters in an either-or group, your expression works. Check it out for yourself: 
https://regex101.com/r/56tz6B/1

Comment: Right you are. I wonder why it's not working in dovecot sieve then... I might just remove those from my filters. (I know I didn't mention dovecot originally, didn't know it was an issue specific to that application)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should also match "blood pressure" without any problems.
Could you try to use `\s+` instead of the space character and see if it works? Please note that this would also match any whitespace (tabs, new lines etc.).